# Identify Offer SDP for Answer in WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc, sdp

Given several Offer SDPs created by the local device, and an Answer SDP created by remote device in reply to one, is it possible to identify the Offer that the Answer was created for?

In other words, is there some information unique to a single connection that is in both the Answer and the Offer, allowing the two to be matched? For example, a value in the SDP saying for which connection the SDP is.

I am not confident of whether or not the same session ID is used both in the Offer and Answer, but if it were, that could be used.

Answer (score 2):

No, standards-compliant JSEP SDP wouldn't have any identifier like that.

One trick you could do (which I wouldn't quite recommend, since it could stop working on any new Chrome/Firefox version) would be using the "a=mid" attribute. This is guaranteed to be the same between the offer and answer.

So, you could take sdp that looks like this:

```
...
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
...
a=mid:audio
...
```

And replace it with

```
...
a=group:BUNDLE uniqueidentifier video
...
a=mid:uniqueidentifier
...
```

Though, as mentioned, this isn't future-proof (since SDP munging will eventually be disallowed). Also, the MID should be small since it will appear on-the-wire, and it needs to be the same between successive offers/answers. I'd really just recommend signaling a unique identifier outside of the SDP itself.